# What happened to Rand's adopted mother?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

She appears at the end of the Eye of the World and at the beginning of A Great Hunt (I think), then I don't believe she comes back. Was this really his mother?

Answer (score 6):

Her name is Kari al'Thor.

According to [A Wheel of Time Wiki](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Kari_al%27Thor):

> She died when Rand was 5 and he doesn't really remember her.

From the wiki:

> "During Rand's confrontation with Ba'alzamon, Kari is used a pawn against Rand. She appears before the Dragon Reborn, surrounded by Fades, who strip and assault her. Rand uses a sword of Light to destroy the Shadowspawn and free her."

Comment: freed her to go where?

Comment: @ Bob Supposedly to the Light. The Great Lord of the Dark is also known to 'lure' souls and spirits to his domain away from the light, at least the souls that had not swore fealty to him in the first place. It is suggested in the writing in the first book that Kari al'Thor had done so to protect her adopted son, Rand, though may have been misled. When Rand defeated Ba'alzammon, Kari al'Thor mentions something to the effect of 'the blessed light' after Ba'alzammon tempts him to basically join the dark side to free the woman he once thought his mother.